# Copy multiple rows within a range

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have macro that looks in another document and copies an offset cell if a value is present. I already have the code below (only the part that selects/copies the offset cell), but it only will copy one row. This is fine for most of the items I am searching for. Does anyone know how to modify the code below to copy all cells that contain my searched value?

```
For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)

Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = Rng.Address
            Do
                'mark the cell in the column to the right if "Ron" is found
                Rng.Offset(0, 4).Select
                'Rng.Copy "A" & Rcount
                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
            Selection.Copy (Rng)
        End If
    Next I
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is a loop for the .Find method.

So you have a range of data namely MyArr imagine its 50 items long. You want to look from 0 to 50 until you find your item.

Lets say you find it in positon 8. Now you do another search but this time from items 9 to 50 and see if you find a match. If you dont you know there are no more. If you do you repeat the above until you run out of elements in the array(range) or you have no more matches. Does that make sense?